# How to organize Ember JS application on a non Rails Application

Tags: ember.js, requirejs

I need to organize my JS files for an Ember Application. I don't have a Rails backend. I am running it of a Java based Glassfish server. Is there any help for this using loader.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the project template, hosted at [interline/ember-skeleton](https://github.com/interline/ember-skeleton). It uses Rake Pipeline and compiles your code into the `assets` folder. If you execute `bundle exec rackup` you can access the application on `http://localhost:9292/index.html`.

It's also possible to created minified version of your code via `RAKEP_MODE=production bundle exec rakep`.

The layout of `ember-skeleton` is basically the same as the one used in the not yet released emberjs gem, which can be found [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-gem).

Comment: Fanstastic. Got it working with Rake and running on Glassfish. Every compilation needs a hot to localhost:9292 though.